# pseudo grid edit icon pops up a jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery

i have a single jquery modal popup box, and i need to use it from many items in a pseudo  grid.

the psuedo grid, edit item icon needs to be pop up the single modal popup passing in a parameter.

This is the code that i have to display the jquery modal popup...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $('div#unassignedWorkstationsPopup').dialog({
    height: 500,
    width: 800,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false
  });
  $('#unassignedWorkstationsLink').click(function () {
    $('div#unassignedWorkstationsPopup').dialog('option', 'buttons', [{ text: 'OK' }]);
    $('div#unassignedWorkstationsPopup').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

and i have a single div that has an image of an edit icon, that needs to call the displaying area of the popup.

but there is where i am lost.

thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question fully. Are you trying to call the dialog from multiple areas? If so assign the click to a class name and not a unique id. Then you can add that element next to every item you want to edit.

Comment: click to a class....   this sounds interesting....  please asvise

Comment: Yea, I would create an element: `<span class="edit-item">Edit</span>`, and add it everywhere you need to edit something, then use `$('.edit-item').on('click', function(){//dialog open});`. Hope that helps!